Mackey theory: Induced representation of the associated algebra
While working with induced representations, I wanted to understand if the induced representation of a group also gives a representation of the corresponding algebra.
I'm working with a group that has the form $S \ltimes \mathbb{R}^n$ and I'm inducing a representation of $S$ on the whole group.
For the induced representation of the translations, this is pretty straight forward. Consider the action of a group element of the rotation parametrized by $\vec{a}$ on a function:
\begin{equation}
(U_{g(\vec{a})} \psi)(\vec{x}) = \psi(\vec{x}-\vec{a}).
\end{equation}
Then to find the action of the algebra, we consider linearized term in the group parameter $\vec{a}$ and find
\begin{equation}
(U_{g(\vec{a})}\psi)(\vec{x}) = \psi(\vec{x}) - \vec{a}\cdot \nabla \psi(\vec{x}) + \mathcal{O}(a^2).
\end{equation}
From which we can deduce that the translation algebra generator act as
\begin{equation}
P_i \psi(\vec{x}) = -\partial_i \psi(\vec{x}).
\end{equation}
Now consider the case of "rotations" ($S$) with elements parametrized by a vector \vec{s}, such that the group element is $g(\vec{s}) = \exp(\vec{s}\cdot \vec{J})$, where $J_i, \, i=1,2,3$ are the generators of the algebra of $S$
We have a representation of the group on functions with a vector index,
\begin{equation}
(U_{g(\vec{s})}\psi^i)(\vec{x}) = R(g)^{ij}\psi^j(\tilde{R}(g)\vec{x}),
\end{equation}
where in general the action of rotation on the homogeneous space doesn't have to be the same as in the vector space of the associated vector bundle. (I'm trying to not get into the details of Mackey theory because I don't think one needs to to answer this question).
What I'm looking for is something similar to the translation case. I want to expand in the $\vec{s}$ parameter to deduce the action of the rotation algebra on such functions. At linear order in $\vec{s}$ one finds something like the following
\begin{equation}
(U_g(\vec{s})\psi^i)(\vec{x}) = (1 + \vec{s}\cdot \vec{J})^{ij} \psi^j(\vec{x} + (\vec{s}\cdot \vec{\tilde{J}})^{ij}x^j).
\end{equation}
Now if we consider the identity coset $x=0$ then we recover the original representation we started with. But in the general case, the term inside the function on the right hand side prevents me of understanding the infinitesimal action and thus the representation of the algebra on the functions.
If anyone has any clues to help me I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks!
